i'm confused how did solana wallet works am I doing this right?
this is SolanaProvider.js
import { Provider } from '@modules/core/provider/base/Provider';
import axios from 'axios';
import {Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl, Transaction, SystemProgram, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL} from '@solana/web3.js';
import {Cluster} from "@solana/web3.js";
export class SolanaProvider implements Provider {
apiInstance: typeof axios; // Axios instance for HTTP requests
connection: Connection;   // Solana connection object
constructor({ rpcUrl, apiEndpoint, apiKey }) {
    this.apiInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: `${apiEndpoint}` || 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com', // Default to Solana mainnet API
        headers: apiKey ? { 'Authorization': apiKey } : {}, // Optional API key
    });
    this.connection = new Connection(rpcUrl || clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta')); // Establish connection to Solana network
}

async getNetwork(): Promise<Cluster> {
    const connection = new Connection(process.env.SOLANA_RPC_URL || 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com', 'confirmed'); // Or use your preferred RPC

    try {
        const version = await connection.getVersion(); // Get the Solana node's version information
        const cluster = version['solana-core'].includes('testnet') ? 'testnet' : 'mainnet-beta'; // Basic cluster identification

        return cluster;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching network information:", error);
        throw new Error('Failed to get network information');
    }
}

async getGasPrice(): Promise<number> {
    // Solana doesn't have a gas price concept like Ethereum.
    // Instead, you pay transaction fees in SOL.
    // Here, you can fetch the recent blockhash to estimate fees:
    const recentBlockhash = await this.connection.getRecentBlockhash();
    return recentBlockhash.feeCalculator.lamportsPerSignature; // Lamports per signature is the fee unit in Solana
}

async getFeeData(): Promise<{ lamportsPerSignature: number }> {
    const connection = new Connection(process.env.SOLANA_RPC_URL || 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com', 'confirmed'); // Or your preferred RPC endpoint

    try {
        const feeCalculator = await connection.getFeeCalculatorForBlockhash(
            await connection.getRecentBlockhash('confirmed'), // Get the recent blockhash
        );

        return { lamportsPerSignature: feeCalculator.value.lamportsPerSignature };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching fee data:", error);
        throw new Error("Failed to get fee data");
    }
}

async estimateGas({ from, to, data }) {
    // In Solana, transaction size influences fees, not gas.
    // You can estimate transaction size here:
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
        SystemProgram.transfer({
            fromPubkey: new PublicKey(from),
            toPubkey: new PublicKey(to),
            lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL / 100, // Example: Transfer 0.01 SOL
        })
    );
    transaction.recentBlockhash = (await this.connection.getRecentBlockhash('finalized')).blockhash;

    const transactionSize = transaction.serialize({requireAllSignatures: false}).length;
    const estimatedFee = transactionSize * await this.getGasPrice();

    return {success: true, data: estimatedFee};
}

async getTransactions(
    address: string,
    limit: number = 10, // Default to fetching 10 transactions
    before?: string, // Optional parameter for pagination
    until?: string, // Optional parameter for pagination
): Promise<Array<any>> { // Adjust type as needed for your transaction representation

    const connection = new Connection(process.env.SOLANA_RPC_URL || 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com', 'confirmed');
    const pubKey = new PublicKey(address);

    try {
        let transactions: Array<any> = [];

        // Fetch signatures first for efficiency (can be batched if needed)
        const signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
            pubKey,
            { limit, before, until }
        );

        // Fetch transaction details for each signature
        for (const signature of signatures) {
            const transaction = await connection.getTransaction(signature.signature, { commitment: 'confirmed' });
            if (transaction) {
                transactions.push(transaction); // Add to the results
            }
        }

        return transactions;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching transactions:", error);
        throw new Error("Failed to get transactions");
    }
}

}
and this is SolanaWallet.js
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import {Logs} from '@modules/log/logs';
import {Keypair, PublicKey, SystemProgram, Transaction} from '@solana/web3.js';
import * as Bip39 from 'bip39';
import {derivePath} from 'ed25519-hd-key';
import bs58 from 'bs58';
import {SolanaProvider} from '@modules/core/provider/solana/SolanaProvider'; // Assuming you have this
import {Wallet} from "ethers";
import { mnemonicToSeedSync } from '@scure/bip39';
export const SOLANA_BIP39_PATH = "m/44'/501'/0'/0'";
export class SolanaWallet implements Wallet{
provider: SolanaProvider;
keypair: Keypair;
constructor(provider: SolanaProvider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}

async mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic: string): Promise<Buffer> {
    // Solana uses the "m/44'/501'/0'/0'" derivation path (hardened)
    const path = "m/44'/501'/0'/0'";
    const seed = mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);

    return derivePath(path, seed.toString('hex')).key;
}

async fromMnemonic(data, mnemonic): Promise<Object> {
    try {
        const seed = await this.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic);
        const derivedSeed = derivePath(SOLANA_BIP39_PATH, seed.toString('hex')).key;
        this.keypair = Keypair.fromSeed(derivedSeed);
        return {
            success: true,
            data: {
                ...data,
                walletAddress: this.keypair.publicKey.toString(),
                privateKey: bs58.encode(this.keypair.secretKey), // Encode to Base58
            },
        };
    } catch (e) {
        Logs.info('SolanaWallet: fromMnemonic', e);
        // ... (Error handling)
    }
}

async fromPrivateKey(data, privateKey): Promise<Object> {
    try {
        this.keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(privateKey)); // Decode from Base58
        return {
            success: true,
            data: {
                ...data,
                walletAddress: this.keypair.publicKey.toString(),
            },
        };
    } catch (e) {
        Logs.info('SolanaWallet: fromPrivateKey', e);
        // ... (Error handling)
    }
}

async sendTransaction({to, value, feePayer}): Promise<Object> {
    try {
        const transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.transfer({
                fromPubkey: this.keypair.publicKey,
                toPubkey: new PublicKey(to),
                lamports: value, // Value should be in lamports
            })
        );

        transaction.feePayer = feePayer || this.keypair.publicKey; // Optionally specify a fee payer
        const blockhash = await this.provider.connection.getRecentBlockhash();
        transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash.blockhash;
        transaction.sign(this.keypair);

        const txid = await this.provider.connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize());
        return {
            success: true,
            data: { txid },
        };

    } catch (e) {
        Logs.info('SolanaWallet: sendTransaction', e);
        // ... (Error handling)
    }
}
async getTransactions(wallet, limit = 20, before = null): Promise<Object> {
    try {
        const signatures = await this.provider.connection.getSignaturesForAddress(
            new PublicKey(wallet.walletAddress),
            { limit, before }
        );

        const transactions = await this.provider.connection.getParsedConfirmedTransactions(signatures.map(s => s.signature));

        return {
            success: true,
            data: transactions.filter(tx => tx !== null).map(tx => { // Filter out null transactions (might occur if not yet confirmed)
                return {
                    signature: tx.transaction.signatures[0],
                    blockTime: tx.blockTime,
                    from: tx.transaction.message.accountKeys[0].pubkey, // Assuming simple transfer
                    to: tx.transaction.message.instructions[0]?.parsed.info.destination,
                    value: tx.transaction.message.instructions[0]?.parsed.info.lamports,
                    fee: tx.meta.fee,
                    status: tx.meta.err ? 'Failed' : 'Success',
                    // ... (Add other relevant fields as needed)
                };
            }),
        };
    } catch (e) {
        Logs.info('SolanaWallet: getTransactions', e);
        return {
            success: false,
            data: [],
        };
    }
}

}

Can you please rephrase your question? Right now it makes little sense.
